# Multiple Stripe Checkout Buttons on One Page

Tags: javascript, html, stripe-payments

I have a variable amount of Stripe Checkout buttons on one page within a `for` loop, which can be different amounts/titles. Unfortunately, the buttons aren't working past the first one. This is what it looks like rendered.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-white mt-3 btn-sm" id="purchaseButton">Add (£20)</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary text-white mt-3 btn-sm" id="purchaseButton">Add (£35)</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary text-white mt-3 btn-sm" id="purchaseButton">Add (£42)</a>
```

Then I have the script being called:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
  }
});

document.getElementById('purchaseButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Stripe.com',
    src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
    class: "stripe-button",
    key: "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh",
    name: "Demo Site",
    email: "{{ currentUser.email }}",
    currency: "gbp",
    description: "{{ entry.title }} - {{ entry.author.username }}",
    amount: "{{ entry.cost * 100 }}"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to only call the script once and send the `amount` via the button dynamically?

Comment: The same 'id' can only used once on a page, otherwise it will use the first one each time. Try changing it to the class name of each and then listen for a click of that class. You would also make the value of each button element equal to the value you want (e.g value="20" for the first one, value="35", for the second, etc). Then obtain the value from within the click function. If the user is adding multiple amounts, you should probably add a "Pay" button also, so your script knows when the user is finished adding amounts and therefore should process the payment.

Comment: Hi Beano, is there a way to add multiple attributes not just value? e.g description?

Comment: You can add as many attributes as you want to your HTML like `data-value="25" data-description="Blah"` and access them in your JavaScript by using `e.target.dataset.value` etc. You also should use a class instead of an ID, because multiple elements with the same ID will not work. More Information on Data Attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: If possible, can someone formulate an answer using the above for others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct procedure to assign the Stripe listener to multiple checkout buttons. Also this example uses plans, change with products as per your question.

First, create your markup with each checkout button having an unique ID.

In the example PHP is used, as a server side language to generate the markup. Change to JavaScript, or whatever you use if it makes more sense in your case.

```
<?php foreach ($planData as $plan) { ?>
    <form method="GET" onsubmit="return false;">
        <?php echo $plan['Title']; ?>
            <button id="checkout-button-<?php echo $plan['Id']; ?>">
                Subscribe
            </button>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Then, on the client side foreach plan entry assign the listener to the corresponding button:

```
$(plans).each(function (index, plan) {
    var checkoutButton = document.querySelector('#checkout-button-' + plan.Id);
    checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{
             // Define the product and plan in the Dashboard first, and use the plan
             // ID in your client-side code.
             plan: plan.StripePlanId,
             quantity: 1
             }],
          successUrl: plan.UrlSubscribeSuccess,
          cancelUrl: plan.UrlSubscribeCancel,
          customerEmail: userEmail
     });
   });
 });
```